# Selecting a subset of rows with MySql: conditionally limiting number of entries selected

Tags: mysql, sql

this is a followup question to my previous query. I hope that posting a new question is appropriate in the circumstances: [Selecting a subset of rows from a PHP table](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17333033/selecting-a-subset-of-rows-from-a-php-table)

I have an sql table that looks like this (for example):

```
id seller price amount
1  tom    350   500
2  tom    350   750
3  tom    350   750
4  tom    370   850
5  jerry  500   1000
```

I want to select one row per seller: in particular, for each seller I want the row with the cheapest price, and the largest amount at that price. In the example above, I want rows 2 and 5 (or 3 and 5, I don't care which of 2 and 3 I get as long as I only get one of them).

I am using this:

```
dbquery("SELECT a.* FROM $marketdb a
        INNER JOIN
        (
            SELECT  seller, MAX(amount) amount
            FROM    $marketdb
            WHERE   price=$minprice
            GROUP   BY seller
        ) b ON a.seller = b.seller AND
                a.amount = b.amount;");
```

But this is giving me rows 2,3 and 5, and I only want one of rows 2 and 3.

I also have a nagging suspicion that this might not always return the minimum price rows either. My tests so far have been confused by the fact that I am getting more than one row with the same amount entered for a given seller.

If someone could point out my error I would be most appreciative.

Thanks!

EDIT: my apologies, I did not ask what I mean to ask. I would like rows returned from the global min price, max 1 per seller, not the min price for each seller. This would be only row 2 or 3 above. Sorry!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just try adding another group by on seller as you want single row for a seller

to final query like

```
SELECT a.* FROM $marketdb a
INNER JOIN
(
    SELECT  seller, MAX(amount) amount
    FROM    $marketdb
    WHERE   price=$minprice
    GROUP   BY seller
) 
b ON a.seller = b.seller AND
a.amount = b.amount group by a.seller;
```

Comment: This does it, with very minor mods to accommodate my carelessness (see edit). Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Test this **SQL fiddle**:

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/7de03/2/0

```
CREATE TABLE `sellers` (
  `id` INT UNSIGNED  NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `seller` VARCHAR(16) NOT NULL,
  `price` FLOAT NOT NULL,
  `amount` INT UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
);
INSERT INTO `sellers` VALUES (1, 'tom', 350, 500);
INSERT INTO `sellers` VALUES (2, 'tom', 350, 750);
INSERT INTO `sellers` VALUES (3, 'tom', 350, 750);
INSERT INTO `sellers` VALUES (4, 'tom', 350, 850);
INSERT INTO `sellers` VALUES (5, 'jerry', 500, 600);
INSERT INTO `sellers` VALUES (6, 'jerry', 500, 1000);
INSERT INTO `sellers` VALUES (7, 'jerry', 500, 800);

SELECT * FROM
(SELECT DISTINCT * FROM sellers ORDER BY price ASC, amount DESC) t0
GROUP BY seller;
```

Kind of... works :)

Comment: Thanks so much for introducing me to the use of SQL fiddle! Enormously helpful!

Answer (score 1):

There's an ugly hack at the end of this answer, but if you don't care which row is returned then I guess it saves some typing. Although, if you really don't care which row is returned, that tends to point to a more fundamental flaw in your schema design!

```
 SELECT x.* 
   FROM market x 
   JOIN 
      ( SELECT seller,MIN(price) min_price FROM market GROUP BY seller) y 
     ON y.seller = x.seller 
    AND y.min_price = x.price
   JOIN 
      ( SELECT seller,price,MAX(amount) max_amount FROM market GROUP BY seller,price) z
     ON z.seller = y.seller 
    AND y.min_price = z.price
    AND z.max_amount = x.amount
  GROUP
     BY seller;
```

Another method, which i dislike but which is popular with others here, goes something like this...

```
SELECT x.*         
  FROM 
     ( SELECT * 
         FROM market
        ORDER
           BY seller
            , price
            , amount DESC
            , id
     ) x
 GROUP
    BY seller;
```

Comment: Your first query does almost exactly what I want. I realize now that I phrased the question wrong. Your query does exactly what I asked in the OP, but what I asked was not quite what I wanted. The change is that I only want rows returned from sellers at the global minimum, not the minimum for each individual seller. So what I would actually get from the example in the OP is only either row 2 or 3. My apologies. I am attempting to mod your example as we speak, with mixed results :)

Answer (score 0):

You may need to `GROUP BY` the seller column outside of the join. Also, your `WHERE` clause looks like where price is a set number, instead of `<=`.

Answer (score 0):

Query:

**[SQLFIDDLEExample](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/3ae63/1)**

```
SELECT s.* 
FROM sellers s 
WHERE s.id = (SELECT s2.id
              FROM sellers s2
              WHERE s2.seller = s.seller
              ORDER BY s2.price ASC, s2.amount DESC
              LIMIT 1)
```

Result:

```
| ID | SELLER | PRICE | AMOUNT |
--------------------------------
|  2 |    tom |   350 |    750 |
|  5 |  jerry |   500 |   1000 |
```